# Redefine an SCSS nesting selector depending on the body class inside of the nesting block

Tags: sass

I have an SCSS ruleset which looks somewhat like this:

```
.thing {
  div {
    // rules
  }
}
```

Sometimes I want to restyle this `.thing div` element depending on a class being added to the `body` so in standard CSS I would have done it like this:

```
.thing div {
  // rules
}

.deactivated .thing div {
  // override for when it's in body.deactivated
}
```

Is there a way to break out of the nest to indicate a top-level enclosing selector in SCSS?

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want to nest, do so something like this:

```
.thing {
  div {
    // rules
  }
}

.deactiviated {
  .thing {
    div {
      // other rules
    }
  }
}
```